# How to restore open files when I close and reopen a project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

For my workflow and code structure, it's very helpful to be able to close and reopen Eclipse projects fairly regularly.  One problem I have however is that when I close a project, it doesn't remember which files were open, so when I reopen the project, it's just an empty screen.

Is there any way to set eclipse to reopen the files that were open when I closed a project, when I reopen it?

Comment: Maybe using Mylin?

Comment: I've only just starting using eclipse about two months ago, and mine always reopens my files. It saves the state of the workspace. Are you using a workspace?

Comment: I'm using a workspace, but the projects are not in the default directory, I manually specified their location at project creation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there's no way to do this per-project, but as mentioned in the comments *workspace* state is saved. I've found that having one workspace per project has been reasonably effective for use-cases that require closing/reopening projects regularly.

It would be nice, of course, if projects worked the same way inside a single workspace, but I don't think that exists presently.